# Filter buttons not combining logic for filtering JSON - mat-dialog

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a filter component. If I choose Buy it Now or Private Auction, they work independently, but not combined. If I have a result that has Buy It Now enabled and Private Auction Enabled, then it will either filter by one or the other, but not by both. How can I get them to work together?

2nd question, if I click outside of the modal, the console throws errors that result is 
undefined from subscribe(). Is there a way I can tell angular when clicking outside to not subscribe?

app.component.ts

```
  openFilterDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FiltersComponent, {
      panelClass: "dialogBoxStyler",
      data: {
        posts: this.posts,
        buyItNowEnabled: this.buyItNowEnabled,
        privateAuctionEnabled: this.privateAuctionEnabled,
        auctionTimeType: this.auctionTimeType
      }
    });

    dialogRef
      .afterClosed()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy))
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log("RESULTS");
        console.log(result);
        this.posts = result.posts;
        this.buyItNowEnabled = result.buyItNowEnabled;
        console.log("result is" + result.auctionTimeType);
        this.privateAuctionEnabled = result.privateAuctionEnabled;
        this.auctionTimeType = result.auctionTimeType;
      });
  }
```

filter.component.ts

```
  confirmFilter(
    privateAuctionEnabled: boolean,
    buyItNowEnabled: boolean,
    auctionTimeType: string
  ) {
    this.auctionTimeType = auctionTimeType;

    if (auctionTimeType === "Ending Soonest") {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.sort((n1, n2) => {
        if (n1.auctionEndDateTime > n2.auctionEndDateTime) {
          return 1;
        }

        if (n1.auctionEndDateTime < n2.auctionEndDateTime) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    if (auctionTimeType === "Newly Listed") {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.sort((n1, n2) => {
        if (n1.auctionEndDateTime > n2.auctionEndDateTime) {
          return 1;
        }

        if (n1.auctionEndDateTime < n2.auctionEndDateTime) {
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }

    if (privateAuctionEnabled) {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter(
        x => x.auctionType === "privateAuction"
      );
    }

    if (buyItNowEnabled) {
      this.filteredPosts = this.posts.filter(
        x => x.buyItNow !== "Not Available"
      );
    }
    var filteredItems = {
      posts: this.filteredPosts,
      buyItNowEnabled: this.buyItNowEnabled,
      privateAuctionEnabled: privateAuctionEnabled,
      auctionTimeType: this.auctionTimeType
    };

    this.dialogRef.close(filteredItems);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if both `buyItNowEnabled` and `privateAuctionEnabled` are true. If they are true then first filter the `posts` using conditions which are required for  `buyItNowEnabled` case and store resulting data in `temp` array. Then again filter this temp array's data using conditions which are required for `privateAuctionEnabled` case and thus the data generated by this filteration will be your final answer.